# Python-Flask using StringEncryptedType and encryption key, what is best practice?

Tags: python, flask, encryption, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt some columns in my sqlite db, but I'm not sure how to store my encryption key. It doesn't feel right that it should be plain text in my code but I'm not sure what else I can do to hide my encryption key but at the same time have it accessible to Flask for encrypting/decrypting data into the sqlite db. This is my code so far:

models.py

```
from flask import current_app
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from sqlalchemy_utils import EncryptedType, StringEncryptedType

key = "this_is_my_key"

if key is None:
    raise ValueError("Encryption key not set.")

class Rx(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rx_number = db.Column(StringEncryptedType(db.TEXT, key), nullable=True, unique=False)
    name = db.Column(StringEncryptedType(db.TEXT, key), nullable=True, unique=False)
    email = db.Column(EncryptedType(db.TEXT, key), nullable=True, unique=False)
```

config.py

```
import os


class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```